# How to dynamically inject property values from a configuration file into Hystrix's annotations

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, hystrix

I am learning Spring Cloud now.

We know that If the remote configuration file is updated, by accessing the “localhost:10000/refresh”, we can dynamically obtain the values of custom properties of the remote configuration file on the configuration server. I would like to ask, how do I dynamically inject these values into Hystrix's annotations.

My remote configuration file “licenseservice.yml”, I put it in a git repository:

example.property: I am the default. I am from git now.

example.timeoutInMilliseconds: 12000

server:
  port: 10000

eureka:
  instance:
    prefer-ip-address: true
...

The java class I used to get the values in the configuration file:

```
@Component
@RefreshScope
public class ServiceConfig {

    @Value("${example.property}")
    private String exampleProperty;

    @Value("${example.timeoutInMilliseconds}")
    private String timeoutInMilliseconds;

    public String getExampleProperty() {
        return exampleProperty;
    }
    public String getTimeoutInMilliseconds(){
        return timeoutInMilliseconds;
    }
}
```

The java method that uses the Hystrix annotations:

```
    @HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "buildFallbackLicenseList",
    threadPoolKey = "licenseByOrgThreadPool",
    threadPoolProperties = {
            @HystrixProperty(name = "coreSize",value = "30"),
            @HystrixProperty(name = "maxQueueSize", value = "10")
    },
    commandProperties = {
            @HystrixProperty(name = 
"circuitBreaker.requestVolumeThreshold",value = "10"),
            @HystrixProperty(name = 
"circuitBreaker.errorThresholdPercentage",value = "75"),
            @HystrixProperty(name = 
"circuitBreaker.sleepWindowInMilliseconds",value = "7000"),
            @HystrixProperty(name = 
"metrics.rollingStats.timeInMilliseconds",value = "15000"),
            @HystrixProperty(name = 
"metrics.rollingStats.numBuckets",value = "5"),
            @HystrixProperty(name = 
"execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds",value = ???)
    })
    public List<License> getLicensesByOrg(String organizationId){
        System.out.println("SERVICE CONFIG TEST 
"+serviceConfig.getExampleProperty());
        System.out.println("SERVICE CONFIG TEST 
"+serviceConfig.getTimeoutInMilliseconds());
        randomlyRunLong();
        return licenseRepository.findByOrganizationId(organizationId);
    }
```

My problem is, I want to dynamically change the value of the variable "execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds"(by using the value of "example.timeoutInMilliseconds" in the .yml file). You can see that I wrote three question marks in that place, because I don't know what to write, can someone please? Tell me, thank you.

Comment: AFAIK `@HystrixCommand` properties are already dynamically updated if you use the documented properties in boot config files (ie without `@HystrixProperty`).